# Changing the width and height of an inline list

Tags: html, css

I have an inline list that I want to be 330px wide and 50px tall. Yet, I am unable to make it the width/height I want. It is only as big as the content it is containing, what am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/Apnx5/

Comment: It is working exactly as you specified it to be. The width of the list is 330px and the height of the list is 50px, as you specified. Did you mean that you want every item to be 330px x 50px?

Comment: Well your list items don't fill the `ul`. Where do you expect the extra space to end up? Evenly distributed amongst the four items?

Comment: @mrtsherman yes, is that possible?

Comment: then you should have said so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with your current html setup. There isn't a way to say, I want these list items to be dynamically sized based on content, but then if there is anything leftover add it on please.

Instead make use of `display: table-cell`. This will require both a markup and css change. Not IE7 compatible, but IE7 is dying a fast death (unlike IE6 did).

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/Apnx5/6/

```
<div id="listed">
        <div class="item"><a href="#"> Profile </a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#"> About </a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#"> Photos </a></div>
        <div class="item"><a href="#"> My Albumlist </a></div>
</div>​

#listed {
    height: 50px;
    width: 330px;
    display: table;
}

div.item {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Comment: Why are HTML changes necessary?  The ul and li elements should be able to take on those styles.

Comment: The answer is correct, but looks horrible. I've fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Apnx5/13/